# get different keys in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array and I want to get all different keys on it.
my json is something like this :

```
{

"odds": {
    "1_2": [
        {
            "id": 3355,
            "handicap": "1.25",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3361,
            "handicap": "1.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 559332,
            "handicap": "+1.0,+1.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 684091,
            "handicap": "+0.5,+1.0",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.150",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.675",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 687351,
            "handicap": "+1",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "1.825",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.975",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 838672,
            "handicap": "+0.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 891523,
            "handicap": "0.0,+0.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 990467,
            "handicap": "-0.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "1.850",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.950",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1154786,
            "handicap": "-0.5,-1.0",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1265769,
            "handicap": "0.0",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.300",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.600",
                "status": "same"
            }
        }
    ],
    "1_3": [
        {
            "id": 3371,
            "handicap": "3.25",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3380,
            "handicap": "3.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 559335,
            "handicap": "3.0,3.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 691481,
            "handicap": "3",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 742454,
            "handicap": "2.5,3.0",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 789160,
            "handicap": "2.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 835770,
            "handicap": "2.0,2.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 882149,
            "handicap": "2",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.750",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.050",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 916746,
            "handicap": "1.5,2.0",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1232302,
            "handicap": "4",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.875",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.925",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1253826,
            "handicap": "3.5,4.0",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.700",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.100",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1355508,
            "handicap": "4.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "3.450",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.300",
                "status": "same"
            }
        }
    ]

}}
```

i tried to get them by this way

```
  for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in [titles[i]]) {
        keys.push(key);
    } 
    console.log(odds[titles[i]][keys[0]]);
```

and i can access to id of each ojbect using this code odds[titles[i]][j].id

how can I access these different keys and show them in my code?
for example, I want to show the home_od name and showing odds and status included in it

Comment: use `foreach` . for handling the arrays

Comment: show desried result format

Answer (score 0):

Here i used `Set`

> A Set is a special type collection – “set of values” (without keys),
>   where each value may occur only once. `Set` – is a collection of unique values

Try this one

```js
const titles = {

"odds": {
    "1_2": [
        {
            "id": 3355,
            "handicap": "1.25",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3361,
            "handicap": "1.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 559332,
            "handicap": "+1.0,+1.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 684091,
            "handicap": "+0.5,+1.0",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.150",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.675",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 687351,
            "handicap": "+1",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "1.825",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.975",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 838672,
            "handicap": "+0.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 891523,
            "handicap": "0.0,+0.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 990467,
            "handicap": "-0.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "1.850",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.950",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1154786,
            "handicap": "-0.5,-1.0",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1265769,
            "handicap": "0.0",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.300",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.600",
                "status": "same"
            }
        }
    ],
    "1_3": [
        {
            "id": 3371,
            "handicap": "3.25",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3380,
            "handicap": "3.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 559335,
            "handicap": "3.0,3.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 691481,
            "handicap": "3",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 742454,
            "handicap": "2.5,3.0",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 789160,
            "handicap": "2.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 835770,
            "handicap": "2.0,2.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 882149,
            "handicap": "2",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.750",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.050",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 916746,
            "handicap": "1.5,2.0",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1232302,
            "handicap": "4",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.875",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.925",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1253826,
            "handicap": "3.5,4.0",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.700",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.100",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1355508,
            "handicap": "4.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "3.450",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.300",
                "status": "same"
            }
        }
    ]

}}
let firstLevelKeyArr = Object.keys(titles.odds); // ['1_2','1_3']


//this block for home_od
let home_odsSet = new Set();
firstLevelKeyArr.map(key => titles.odds[key].map(item => {
   if(item.home_od){
      home_odsSet.add(item.home_od);
    }
 })
)

let home_odsValues = [];
for (let home_ods of home_odsSet) {
  home_odsValues.push(home_ods);
}
console.log(home_odsValues)

//this block for id
let idSet= new Set();

firstLevelKeyArr.map(key => titles.odds[key].map(item => {
    if(item.id){
       idSet.add(item.id);
    }
  })
)
let idValues = [];
for (let id of idSet) {
  idValues.push(id);
}
console.log(idValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following working code to convert into desired array of objects to display in UI.

Where each object will have

```
  {
    "key": "1_2",
    "id": 3355,
    "name-home_od": "home_od",
    "odds-home_od": "2.000",
    "name-away_od": "away_od",
    "odds-away_od": "1.800"
  }
```

`name-home_od` split it by `-` you will get `home-od` to update in UI.
`odds-home_od` split it by `-` you will get `home-od.odds` to update in UI.

Hope this helps. (one line of code ;)

```js
const input = {

"odds": {
    "1_2": [
        {
            "id": 3355,
            "handicap": "1.25",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3361,
            "handicap": "1.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 559332,
            "handicap": "+1.0,+1.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 684091,
            "handicap": "+0.5,+1.0",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.150",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.675",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 687351,
            "handicap": "+1",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "1.825",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.975",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 838672,
            "handicap": "+0.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 891523,
            "handicap": "0.0,+0.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 990467,
            "handicap": "-0.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "1.850",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.950",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1154786,
            "handicap": "-0.5,-1.0",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1265769,
            "handicap": "0.0",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.300",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.600",
                "status": "same"
            }
        }
    ],
    "1_3": [
        {
            "id": 3371,
            "handicap": "3.25",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3380,
            "handicap": "3.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 559335,
            "handicap": "3.0,3.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 691481,
            "handicap": "3",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 742454,
            "handicap": "2.5,3.0",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 789160,
            "handicap": "2.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 835770,
            "handicap": "2.0,2.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 882149,
            "handicap": "2",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.750",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.050",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 916746,
            "handicap": "1.5,2.0",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1232302,
            "handicap": "4",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.875",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.925",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1253826,
            "handicap": "3.5,4.0",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.700",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.100",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1355508,
            "handicap": "4.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "3.450",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.300",
                "status": "same"
            }
        }
    ]

}}



const flat_objs = Object.keys(input.odds)
  .reduce(
    (acc, curr) => [
      ...acc,
      ...input.odds[curr].map(item => ({ ...item, key: curr }))
    ],
    []
  )
  .map(obj => ({
    key: obj.key,
    id: obj.id,
    ...Object.keys(obj)
      .filter(f => f.includes("_"))
      .reduce(
        (acc, curr) => ({
          ...acc,
          [`name-${curr}`]: curr,
          [`odds-${curr}`]: obj[curr].odds
        }),
        {}
      )
  }));
  
console.log(flat_objs)

for (let obj of flat_objs) {
  Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(f => f.includes("name-"))
    .map(key =>
      console.log(
        "name: ",
        key.split("-")[1],
        ", odds: ",
        obj[`odds-${key.split("-")[1]}`]
      )
    );
}
```

example to extract the name and odds.

```
for (let obj of flat_objs) {
  Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(f => f.includes("name-"))
    .map(key =>
      console.log(
        "name: ",
        key.split("-")[1],
        ", odds: ",
        obj[`odds-${key.split("-")[1]}`]
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: @tedaxe3646, I have updated the code snippet (also in answer). You can run and see and example of getting the name. Similarly based on your requirement, you can update it.

Comment: @tedaxe3646, np! updated the answer to extract both name and odds.

Answer (score 0):

```
Just call function findInObj and pass property name
```

```js
  var titles = {

"odds": {
    "1_2": [
        {
            "id": 3355,
            "handicap": "1.25",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3361,
            "handicap": "1.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 559332,
            "handicap": "+1.0,+1.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 684091,
            "handicap": "+0.5,+1.0",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.150",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.675",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 687351,
            "handicap": "+1",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "1.825",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.975",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 838672,
            "handicap": "+0.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 891523,
            "handicap": "0.0,+0.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 990467,
            "handicap": "-0.5",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "1.850",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.950",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1154786,
            "handicap": "-0.5,-1.0",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1265769,
            "handicap": "0.0",
            "home_od": {
                "odds": "2.300",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "away_od": {
                "odds": "1.600",
                "status": "same"
            }
        }
    ],
    "1_3": [
        {
            "id": 3371,
            "handicap": "3.25",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3380,
            "handicap": "3.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 559335,
            "handicap": "3.0,3.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.900",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 691481,
            "handicap": "3",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 742454,
            "handicap": "2.5,3.0",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 789160,
            "handicap": "2.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.800",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.000",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 835770,
            "handicap": "2.0,2.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 882149,
            "handicap": "2",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.750",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.050",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 916746,
            "handicap": "1.5,2.0",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.775",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.025",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1232302,
            "handicap": "4",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.875",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.925",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1253826,
            "handicap": "3.5,4.0",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "1.700",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "2.100",
                "status": "same"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1355508,
            "handicap": "4.5",
            "over_od": {
                "odds": "3.450",
                "status": "same"
            },
            "under_od": {
                "odds": "1.300",
                "status": "same"
            }
        }
    ]

}}

var foundProp = []; function findInObj(object, properties) {
    if (properties != null) {
        for (var k in object) {
            if (k.toLowerCase() === properties.toLowerCase()) {
                foundProp.push({'Key':k,'Value':object[k]})
            }
            if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
                findInObj(object[k], properties);
            }
        }
    }}
    
    foundProp= []; 
    findInObj(titles,'id');
    console.log(foundProp)
```

```
var foundProp = []; 
function findInObj(object, properties) {
    if (properties != null) {
        for (var k in object) {
            if (k.toLowerCase() === properties.toLowerCase()) {
                foundProp.push({'Key':k,'Value':object[k]})
            }
            if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
                findInObj(object[k], properties);
            }
        }
    }}

    foundProp= []; 
    findInObj(titles,'id');
    findInObj(titles,'status');

    console.log(foundProp)
```